# Difference between Tomcat war file and eclipse war file

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, war

What is the difference and similarity between war file which we are creating in eclipse and which we are creating in tomcat folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

war files are not generated by the tomcat. When web project build, war files are generated and it can be automatically deploy to the configured tomcat by in the eclipse.